# How to Push Sqlite File into Android Device?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am pulling Sql file using below commands and then how to push the file into device?

```
$ adb -d shell
$ run-as your.package.name
$ cat /data/data/your.package.name/databases/yourdatabasename  >/sdcard/yourdatabasename
```

Comment: you can also do this using GUI

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of my win batch file i've created for myself for pushing sqlite db to android device or emulator (root access is not required). You can put this file on your windows desktop to directory containing db file you want to push to android device. I hope the source are self-explained but i am ready to answer the questions. Also i will be grateful for comments, ideas etc.

This script was checked on API 27 Intel X86 emulator and ASUS_Z00ED android 6.0.1 without root access.

```
------------------ pull_waitlist_db.bat-------------------------------------
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
set dbpath=/data/data/com.example.android.waitlist/databases/waitlist.db
set package=com.example.android.waitlist
set remotename=waitlist.db

adb shell "run-as %package% chmod 666 %dbpath%"
adb exec-out run-as %package% cat %dbpath% > %remotename%
adb shell "run-as %package% chmod 600 %dbpath%"

cmd /k
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is not pulling?